# OSX 10.10 Terminal. Help Needed

Tags: terminal, osx-yosemite

Dumb question in my terminal I make documents using the touch command. For example:

```
touch blah.pages    
touch blah.numbers
```

The file was created, but I cant open it.
I'm curious as to why this is. Please help me!

Comment: What are you using to open the file.

Comment: In the terminal I use open. Like open blah.pages. I tried to open it the normal way as well but it wont open.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using Pages and Numbers respectively to open these files, since that's the default.

These programs can't open Pages or Numbers files not created within them, for whatever reason.

You *can* open the files in another editor though, like `nano` for example.

Try `nano blah.pages` and you can edit the empty file.